# Linked List problems with process sync

Tags: c, synchronization, linked-list

This program is a work in progress. It is going to simulate a multiprocessor and I am programming it with producer-consumer sync.

Few problems here:

### - My pending_request counter starts 1 lower than it should and goes down to -1. It should stop at 0.

### - My remove_queue function also keeps removing one over. It will remove until the list is blank, but it doesn't recognize the list is empty. Then if I run remove_queue one more time, then it recognizes the list empty. SAMPLE OUTPUT AT THE BOTTOM at http://tinyurl.com/3ftytol

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct pr_struct{
        int owner;
        int burst_time;
        struct pr_struct *next_prcmd;
} prcmd_t;
static prcmd_t *pr_head = NULL;
static prcmd_t *pr_tail = NULL;
static int pending_request = 0;
static pthread_mutex_t prmutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;


int add_queue(prcmd_t *node)
{       pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);
        //code
        prcmd_t *curNode = pr_head;
        if(pr_head == NULL) { pr_head = node; return;}
        while(curNode->next_prcmd)
        {
              curNode = curNode->next_prcmd;
        }
        curNode->next_prcmd = node;

        //
        pending_request++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(0);
}


int remove_queue(prcmd_t **node)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&prmutex);

    if(pr_head == NULL)
    {
        //your code
        printf("Queue is empty\n");
        //
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(-1);
    }
    else
    {
        //your code
        prcmd_t *tempNode; tempNode = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
        tempNode = *node;
        *node = tempNode->next_prcmd;
        free(tempNode);
        //
        pending_request--;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&prmutex);
        return(0);
    }
}


int get_number_request(void)
    { return pending_request; }

void display_list(prcmd_t *node)
{

    if (pr_head == NULL)
    {

        printf("List is empty!\n\n");
    }


    printf("-----------\n");
    while(node)
    {
        printf("%i  %i\n", node->owner,node->burst_time);
        node = node->next_prcmd;
    }
    int r = get_number_request();
    printf("Pending requests: %i\n", r);
}


int main()
{

    int i=0;
    int length = 4;
    prcmd_t *pr[length];
    for(i =0;i<length;i++)
    {
        pr[i] = (prcmd_t*)malloc(sizeof(prcmd_t));
        pr[i]->owner = i+1;
        pr[i]->burst_time = i + 2;
        add_queue(pr[i]);
    }


    display_list(pr_head);  

    remove_queue(&pr_head);
    display_list(pr_head);
    remove_queue(&pr_head);
    display_list(pr_head);
    remove_queue(&pr_head);
    display_list(pr_head);
    remove_queue(&pr_head);
    display_list(pr_head);
    remove_queue(&pr_head);
    display_list(pr_head);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some things (although maybe not all):

There is no need for a tail pointer if the list is not doubly linked, because there is no way to go from tail to head (no previous pointer)

Why do you malloc in your remove queue?

```
*node = prHead;
prHead = prHead->next_prcmd;
--pending_request;
```

in add_queue you have to `node->next_prcmd = NULL;` otherwwise you will never know the end.

again, some things, but maybe not all...

Mario